# Rails Admin works in development and not Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm developing an app that contains Rails Admin and CanCan.
I only have a users table and not an admin table.
The user table has an Boolean attribute called admin.

Rails Admin works fine in development, but when I try to access it on Heroku, I get:

```
        Started GET "/admin" for 70.34.8.244 at 2012-02-21 20:32:31 +0000

    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "admins" does not exist
                SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
                  FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                     ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                 WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'::regclass
                   AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                 ORDER BY a.attnum
    ):



 cache: [GET /admin] miss
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: did you rake db:migrate?

Comment: Yes - but I'll try again $ heroku run rake db:migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had deleted a file and up to this point I had never used the `git rm` command.
So, Heroku still had that file.

Answer (score 0):

Checklist:

1. Make sure you remembered to migrate your database in Heroku.
2. Show the controller code that is backing `/admin`
3. The red flag for me is that it's looking for "admins" not "admin" as the column name. Could be a simple typo.

Comment: The current version of my project doesn't contain any admin controller.

The initializer for Rails Admin has:

 ` config.current_user_method { current_user } # auto-generated
  
  # Set the admin name here (optional second array element will appear in a beautiful RailsAdmin red ©)
  config.main_app_name = ['Amerequest', 'Admin']
  # or for a dynamic name:
  # config.main_app_name = Proc.new { |controller| [Rails.application.engine_name.titleize, controller.params['action'].titleize] }

And routes.rb has:
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/ame', :as => 'rails_admin'`

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing the same problem. I even tried a heroku db:push to see that the schema migrates properly but still the error (only for /admin link). Looks like some problem in rails_admin gem.

Searching the internet it looks like we need to precompile the assets. Maybe that is causing the error. Will try and let you know.

UPDATE: YES it solved the problem. You need to run below command locally to pre-compile your assets and then do a git commit and push to heroku. That should resolve the problem.
    rake assets:precompile

```
git add -A

git commit -am "Whatever Your Comment"

git push -u origin master

git push heroku master
```

And you will see that your app's /admin link works fine now.

Mark it as answer if this resolves your problem.

Comment: Ari,  for me it was just removing files from git.  But, thanks for the info.

Comment: rake assets:precompile can get messy (puts all the asset files in your project) so I try to avoid it.  To get rails_admin to work on heroku without precompiling the assets locally, put these lines in your application.rb:

`# Prevent initializing the application before assets are precompiled (required for heroku)
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`
`# Add Rails Admin assets (required)
config.assets.precompile += ['rails_admin/rails_admin.css', 'rails_admin/rails_admin.js']`